# WSUS: Get-WsusComputer shows fewer compters than "Update Services" Snap-In

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a Powershell script to query WSUS Data.

I am using `Get-WsusComputer -All` to query all WSUS Clients to determine which Computers have not reported in for a longer Period of time.

However powershell only Returns 3070 Computers where the "Update Services" MMC Snapin is showing 3360 Computers.

What could be the reason for this mismatch?

Comment: FWIW, I am not able to reproduce this on one of my WSUS servers. On the other, I can't run the cmdlet at all (investigating why, something on my end). In general, I've noticed that the WSUS cmdlets are very buggy, don't give useful errors or `-Verbose` information, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you have at least one Downstream Server with clients.

If you use the `-IncludeDownstreamComputerTargets` parameter instead of `-All` you should get the same count that shows up in the WSUS MMC Snapin's "All Computers" listing.

I think the Help text of `Get-WSUSComputer` is wrong as it states "Specifies that clients of a downstream server should be included, *not clients of this server*."  The way this functions clearly shows that last clause to be incorrect.

From my WSUS:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WsusComputer -All).Count
1036
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WsusComputer -IncludeDownstreamComputerTargets).Count
1198
```

[image]

Comment: That is correct, with -IncludeDownstreamComputerTargets i see all Clients now, thanks